# Drupal Commerce dynamic shipping/payment checkout pane

Tags: commerce

I am building a shop with Drupal Commerce with multiple shipping and payment options configured with Rules. I have both on a single checkout pane and want to update each other when user makes a choice based on defined rules.

Can this be configured in UI or I need some custom AJAX?